# batch renaming files using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-rename, rename-item-cmdlet

I am able to batch rename files in a working directory by using:

```
Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("0{0}.wav" -f $nr++)}
```

However I want the file rename to start at something other than zero. Say 0500, and rename sequentially in order.

```
Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("0{500}.wav" -f $nr++)}
```

returns error.

How can I tell rename to start at a number other than 0?

Comment: simply initialize the counter to the starting number like `$nr = 500`. As aside, by just doing `Dir`, you are playing with fire because that will get you all files and folders in the current directory. Better add the path, a file filter and the `-File` switch to have it only rename .wav files: `(Get-ChildItem -Path '<TheFolder>' -Filter '*.wav' -File)`

Comment: adding `$nr = 500` at the beginning also returns error. I don't mind doing all in `Dir` since I know what is in the working directory and only run it when I need it. Adding the file path can sometimes be long and cumbersome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the counter beforehand to 500.  Also, you don't need to use a ForEach-Object loop (`%`) for this, because the `NewName` parameter can take a scriptblock.

Important here is that you need to put the `Get-ChildItem` part in between brackets to let that finish before renaming the items, otherwise you may end up trying to rename files that have already been renamed.

```
$nr = 500
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.wav' -File) | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:D4}{1}' -f ($script:nr++), $_.Extension }
```

Comment: okay, I thought that the loop would eliminate the need to worry about renaming files that have already been renamed. But in your example you pass a path, i don't want this as I'll already be in the working directory and having to type the dir again can be cumbersome.

Comment: @Fernan then leave out the path